# Using regexes to emulate wild cards (globs)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to JavaScript regexes and I am trying to create a wild card search based on the input text field, where user can enter the criteria using asterisk (`*`).

For ex: User can search for, `*man` (or) `man*` (or) `man` (or) `*man*`, so I am expecting a result like,

1) `man*` = should return only the word starts with man (manager) but should ignore "performance",

2) `*man` = should return only the word ends with man (human). it should not return "manager" as well as "performance",

3) `*man*` = This should return the word that exists anywhere in the string.

The following function works partially but does not look for the beginning of the word while searching for `man*` (i.e. it returns "performance" as well)

```
function wildCardSearch(grdText, query) {
  var queryPattern = query.replace(/\*/g, '\\w');
  var queryRegex = new RegExp(queryPattern, 'i');        
  if (grdText.match(queryRegex))
    return true;
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Ok. Finally, I have found the solution, which combines @wared's solution and mine. Thanks very much for all of your answers.    `var queryPattern;var queryRegex; 
        if (query.indexOf('*') != -1) {
            queryPattern = query
        .replace(/^([^*])|([^*])$/g, '$2\\b$1')
        .replace(/\*/g, '');            
        }
        else {
            queryPattern = query.replace(/\*/g, '\\w');            
        }

        queryRegex = new RegExp(queryPattern, 'i');
        if (queryRegex.test(grdText))
            return true; `

Comment: Consider this sentence : `if (queryRegex.test(grdText)) return true;`. `return true` is useless since `test` already returns a boolean (`true` or `false`). Moreover, your function currently returns `undefined` instead of `false`. You could simply return the result of `test` like this : `return queryRegex.test(grdText);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following :

```
function wildCardSearch(grdText, query) {
    var queryPattern = query
        .replace(/^([^*])|([^*])$/g, '$2\\b$1')
        .replace(/\*/g, '');
    var queryRegex = new RegExp(queryPattern, 'i');
    return queryRegex.test(grdText);
}
```

The result for each search :

```
wildCardSearch('performance', 'man')   // /\bman\b/i -> false
wildCardSearch('performance', 'man*')  // /\bman/i   -> false
wildCardSearch('performance', '*man')  // /man\b/i   -> false
wildCardSearch('performance', '*man*') // /man/i     -> true
```

Paste the code above into a browser console for checking.

Comment: Your code works but I am looking for a different scenario where grdText value may contains more than one single word. For ex: "My performance year", so passing query as (per*) should return true and for (man*) it should return false.

Comment: @Maneshwar I got it after reading your previous comment. Answer updated.

Comment: I think we are pretty close but there seems to be a small issue. I just modified your code to use match.                              var queryPattern = query
.replace(/^([^*])|([^*])$/g, '$2\\b$1')
.replace(/\*/g, '');
var queryRegex = new RegExp(queryPattern, 'i');
if (grdText.match(queryRegex))
return true;   
When i tried with simple text "Man" then it does not return any value but for "Man*" it gives the correct result and the search is also across the string which is exactly I am looking for. Any reason why "Man" did not give any result, it is suppose to search the same way "*Man*"

Comment: @Maneshwar `/*/g` misses a backslash : `/\*/g`. I wonder why you removed it :/

Comment: @Maneshwar If you only want your function to return a boolean, `test` is perfect for this job. I suggest you not to use `match` which creates and populates an array with sub-matches.

Comment: I have not removed it. It is in my code but while I was posting in the comments, I think it got removed automatically by syntax checker. This is the only code I changed it - if (grdText.match(queryRegex))
                    return true;

Comment: Ok. I changed it back to test as you suggested but still I am not getting the desired result for "man" but works perfectly for "man*" and for "\*man*"

Comment: @Maneshwar I thought that a query like `"man"` was intended to match only the entire word, `" man "`. Indeed, `"man*"` means "starts with `man`", `"*man"` means "ends with `man`", so, `"man"` should stand for "starts and ends with `man`".

Answer (score 0):

You could anchor it:
`wildCardSearch("mance","^man*")`. Adding ^ at the beggining it means that it must start with the specified string, and adding $ at the end says that it must end with the specified string. You could modify your function to check, if there is no * at the beginning of the string, you can add the ^ anchor.

```
function wildCardSearch(grdText, query) {
    if(query[0]!='*')
        query = "\\b"+query;
    var queryPattern = query.replace(/\*/g, '\\w');
    var queryRegex = new RegExp(queryPattern, 'i');        
    if (grdText.match(queryRegex))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

here is the working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/NxstY/

Comment: I just checked in the working demo and it works as expected but when the grdText value is a string with more than one word then it returns false. For ex: "I am Manager"

Comment: Absolutely right, so why are you adding `\b` instead of `^`.  Also, you're repeating the OP's mistake of replacing the `*` with `\w`.  As I understand it, the `*` wild card translates to the regex `[^*]*`.

Comment: alert(wildCardSearch("I am manager","man*")) i am expecting this function call to return True because I want to search the entire string, so in this case "manager" exists in the string. May be a split and for loop is required to search each word in the string?

Comment: Okay, maybe you do need to use word boundaries.  But that's not how wild cards/globs traditionally work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wildCardSearch(grdText, query) {
  if(query.indexOf('*') != -1)
    var queryPattern = query.replace(/\*/g, '.*');
  else
    var queryPattern = '.*' + query + '.*';
  var queryRegex = new RegExp('^' + queryPattern + '$', 'i');        
  if (grdText.match(queryRegex))
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your function works almost correctly but with same exception that when grdText contains a string (I am manager) rather than a single word (manager) then it does not work for query(man*)